# How to add transition effect for layouts in android when using intents

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How to add transition effect for layouts in android when using intents.

from one layout to another.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transition effects and Intents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507057/transition-effects-and-intents)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add transition effects when you shift from one Activity to other, use the following code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
i.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(i);

/** Fading Transition Effect */
First.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

Comment: @Androiduser for this, you have to create your own animation xml file

Comment: Thanks Sahil...do u knw hw to get a 3d flip effect in trasition..Is there any xml for that??

Answer (score 2):

So for the animation use the code in OnCreate() of second activity as:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

Or

After intent

```
    First.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
```

This will help you alot.
Following links will help you:[Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389501/activity-transition-in-android)

[Animation2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925355/android-fadeout-animation-for-splash-screen)